# SQL Server - SUM Function giving Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I simplified the example below,  it is actually part of a larger query,  so I do need to restrict the sum call as it's part of the select clause in a larger query I'm building.

I've done some searching on this but am still confused. I'm a developer and not a SQL guru so I could be missing something obvious but I'm fairly perplexed.

In terms of pseudo code, what I would be trying to do is this:

Assume I have a collection of objects that match the base query (so, records that match the clause `where field4 = '1111' and field2 = '201510'`.

Then I iterate through each of these, and, using the value from the current record, I want to perform the sum function:

```
(SELECT SUM(ISNULL(t1.field3,0)) 
 FROM table1 
 where field1 = t1.field1 and field2= t1.field2) SummedValue
```

I envision it "looping through" and doing a SUM, with each, so, for example, if in one of these iterations it has a vale of `field1 = '3433'` and `field2='201510;`, then it would SUM all records from `field3` that match this, however I get the error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

This is the SQL I'm using:

```
SELECT
distinct
(SELECT SUM(ISNULL(t1.field3,0)) FROM table1 where field1 = t1.field1 and field2= t1.field2) SummedValue,
t1.field1,
t1.field2
from 
table1 t1 where field4 = '1111' and field2 = '201510'
GROUP BY t1.field1, field2
```

I think I'm misunderstanding something, would appreciate any advice on what I am doing wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use no need for `DISTINCT` when you use `GROUP BY`
2. Format your code
3. No need for correlated subquery, just simple aggregate function `SUM`

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/376866)**</kbd>

```
CREATE TABLE #table1(field1 INT, field2 INT, field3 INT, field4 INT);

INSERT INTO #table1 VALUES(1, 201510, 3, 1111);
INSERT INTO #table1 VALUES(1, 201510, 3, 1111);
INSERT INTO #table1 VALUES(1, 201510, NULL, 1111);

SELECT
  t1.field1,
  t1.field2,
  [SummedValue] = SUM(ISNULL(t1.field3, 0))             
FROM #table1 t1 
WHERE t1.field4 = '1111' 
  AND t1.field2 = '201510'
GROUP BY t1.field1, field2;
```

Comment: Thanks,  I think I oversimplified my example because this is actually part of a larger query,  so I would actually need to restrict the sum query,  as it's part of the select clause in a query I'm building,  is there a way to put conditions on the sum along the lines of what I was originally trying?

Comment: @RickDane I cannot see whole picture so I can only gues. How about adding `TOP 1` like [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/376899)?

Comment: thanks for the help, the answer you gave makes sense for the question the way I asked it so I'll mark it answered and just make a new post for the bigger picture since it's a bit more complex and I think that would be more clear.